# Groovy Rest Client: Error parsing 'application/json

Tags: groovy, rest-client, jenkins-groovy

I need to use a simple REST API, which returns either 'true' or 'false'(without any braces).

When I tried calling this API using Groovy Rest Client in a Gradle file, from Jenkins, I am getting below exception.

**Error parsing 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' response
groovy.json.JsonException: A JSON payload should start with an openning curly brace '{' or an openning square bracket '['.
Instead, 'true' was found on line: 1, column: 1**

Note: This code is running fine

1. when called from command Line
2. when called from Chrome plugin 'Postman'
3. when called from eclipse in my machine

Code:

```
response1 = client.get  (
                            path: 'updatetenantState'
                            ,query : [tenantId :tenant_id, inActive:true]
                            ,requestContentType: ContentType.JSON
                            ,headers: [Accept: 'application/json']
                        )
```

I am stuck on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use another rest client or json parser.

Comment: Hi daggett, I cant use different parser, since there are many methods already written using this client

Answer (score 2):

don't know what library you are using, but the error

> A JSON payload should start with an openning curly brace '{' or an openning square bracket '['

is a result of using `JsonSlurperClassic` to parse the string `'true'`

```
import groovy.json.*
new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText('true')
```

however the `JsonSlurper` works fine

```
import groovy.json.*
new JsonSlurper().parseText('true')
```

so you just need to change a way of response parsing